# Why kafka logManager need broker-level lock ( logCreationOrDeletionLock )? this lock may cause a decrease in the speed of creating topics

Tags: apache-kafka

Why kafka logManager need  broker-level lock ( logCreationOrDeletionLock )?
In some file systems (eg NFS), this lock may cause a significant decrease in the speed of creating topics.

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/log/LogManager.scala#L86

Comment: The lock is per broker, right? Not "global" to cluster. Meanwhile topics can be created on any broker

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, "global lock" means broker level. In some file systems (eg NFS), this locking may cause a significant decrease in the speed of creating topic which with a lots of partitions. Creating a partition on one broker at the same time will compete for this lock.

Comment: It's not an answer it's a question. Then it's not truly global if there's one per server... Kafka ideally shouldn't use NFS / remote storage for disks anyway. If this code is a problem, perhaps you could try other messaging solutions like Redpanda, Pulsar, WarpStream, NATS, etc?

Comment: thanks, I just want to know the reason for the design of this code. and as you mentioned, why is Kafka not suitable for using remote fs like nfs ?

Comment: NFS has its own locking mechanisms, and is a remote network call for every read/write. Kafka prefers local JBOD (with spinning disks) for speed and resiliency